# Redshift Query to fetch difference of dates

Tags: sql, datetime, amazon-redshift, date-arithmetic

I have 2 columns start_date and end_date, I need to derive a third column as date_diff as below:

[image: start_date end_date]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Redshift, you can use [`datediff()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEDIFF_function.html) and arithmetics:

```
select t.*, datediff(second, start_date, end_date) / 60.0 / 60 / 24 as diff
from mytable t
```

`datediff()` counts the number of boundaries that are crossed between the two date expressions given as second and third argument, expressed in the unit given as first argument. Since you want a result as a decimal number of days, you can use unit `day`: instead, you can compute the difference in seconds, then convert that to a decimal number of days.

Of course, this assumes that you are storing your dates as `timestamp`s (or the-like). If you have strings instead, then you need to cast them first, eg using `to_timestamp()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked the way it is intended to work.